# Angular *ngIf Condition with OR in component html

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I am trying to get an *ngIf with an OR but the second option is ignored.

Here is the code:

```
<div *ngIf="router.url != '/one' || router.url != '/two'">
  show something
</div>
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: The code you provided looks fine. Anymore details you could provide?

Comment: check that value of router.url as condition is correct. What is router? if its activated route i think url is observable.

Comment: Where exactly do you have this div? In the Component that is displayed on route change or on the Component where you have the router-outlet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct that you second condition is ignored, as when `router.url != '/one'` it already satisfies condition and second one is never evaluated, try this way

```
<div *ngIf="!(router.url == '/one' || router.url == '/two')">
  show something
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `router.url != '/one' || router.url != '/two'` means:

```
If router.url != '/one' returns true

If router.url != '/two' returns true
```

The second condition is never evaluated if the first condition is met because you are using OR

Answer (score 0):

Run this code, maybe it'll explain something:

```html
<p>Current URL: {{ router.url }}</p>
<p>Statement: router.url != '/one' - <strong>{{ router.url != '/one' }}</strong></p>
<p>Statement: router.url != '/two' - <strong>{{ router.url != '/two' }}</strong></p>
<p>Statement: router.url != '/one' || router.url != '/two' - <strong>{{ router.url != '/one' || router.url != '/two' }}</strong></p>
<div *ngIf="router.url != '/one' || router.url != '/two'">
  show something
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is always true, because it checks if a value is either different from either one or another. So the condition would only be false if `router.url` were at the same time equal to both `'/one'` and `'/two'`, which is logically impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Check your values to make sure the problem is not related to your data and replace `!=` by `!==`.

However, in your case, I think you should be using and `&&`, because with an `||`, your div will show up since if your route is `/one` or `/two` the condition will be true.

Try this:

```
<div *ngIf="router.url !== '/one' && router.url !== '/two'">
  show something
</div>
```

Which is the same as:

```
<div *ngIf="!(router.url === '/one' || router.url === '/two')">
  show something
</div>
```